# How to compute the envelop of signal in js

Tags: javascript, envelope, audio-analysis

I have a system that register sound from guitar chords to an Arduino. The result for each chord is an array of numbers between 0 and 1024. So one array represent an audio spectrum.
I send each array to a nodeJS server. I'd like to compute the envelope of each audio spectrum, but i dunno how to achieve that. If possible, I'd prefer to use a javascript solution, as my server is in javascript.

I add an approximate drawing. What I have is the blue data ; what I want is an array containing the red data.

[image]

Comment: You could explore ADSRNode  https://github.com/voidqk/adsrnode

Comment: I have this impression that it makes the exact opposite that I want : it created an envelope from data, decay, sustain and release. I have a signal and need a function to retrieve the envelope